# Connect to Mysql option not shown in MS Visual Studio 2017

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012

I am new to MS Visual Studio & have downloaded & installed v2017 rc2.

I downloaded [MySQL for Visual Studio](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/), but even after a reboot, when I select Tools/Connect to database, I only see options for MS & Oracle, nothing for MySql.

Maybe it doesn't work with v 2017?

Actually, I just need a code a short command line program to run a `SELECT` and convert the result to CSV, so am open to any free IDE/Compiler solution for Windows 10.

Comment: In pretty sure the my sql workbench will do that https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL for Visual Studio 2017 has only recently been released. More info at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html